# Disable a button on header from mobile view

Tags: css

I am trying to disable a button on header from mobile view.
Website: http://abeja.com.tr you can see green DEMO button on header.
I tried this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .fancybox-inline {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

also this

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .fancybox-inline {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: css classes have a `.` before them...learn how to use the console to inspect css live, it will show you the issues

Comment: sorry but i already used with .

Comment: FYI : its not a button, its an image wrapped by anchor tag. use F12 in chrome and inspect that element. you can see then. and coming to your question: you can not disable a button just adding display none or visibility hidden. you have to use disable attribute.

Comment: ok, its an image but i can't hide it on mobile view.

Comment: checked your console, there are no styles defined for fancybox-inline ..check you are adding to the correct stylesheet/ css is not cached

Comment: sorry but i couldnt understand what i should do..

Comment: by the way without @media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) its hiding from everywhere.